# How can I describe and call a function of a type of object in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Well, I am learning TypeScript right now and am getting a problem. I do not know the reason.

When I call the function of an object, Visual Studio Code throws an error that type of {} has no call signatures.

I've tried to describe the type of function, but I failed.

```
console.log(b.<object>fn())
```

```
let b: { name: string; fn: {} }

b = {
  name: 'derek',
  fn: (): void => {
    console.log('i am a function')
  }
}

console.log(b.fn())
```

Comment: The type of the function is `() => void`, not `{}`. Alternatively write `fn(): void;`

Comment: Also do not attempt to pass a type parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, functions are usually typed using arrow notation to describe the function signature. So the type of a parameterless function that has no return value would be `() => void`.

In your example, the property `fn` of `b` should have that type:

```
let b: { name: string; fn: () => void }
```

`{}` in TypeScript is used to represent something that can be ***any*** non-nullish value (anything that isn't `null` or `undefined`), meaning it's not guaranteed to be a callable function.

Answer (score 0):

`fn` should be of type `() => void` based on your definition:

```
let b: { name: string; fn: () => void }
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=40&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBARgXBDeEB2BDAtiOBnMAnAlkgOYDcEAZknABQCUEAvAHwQBuA9vgCYQC+AsACghURgiERk6TBADkXELhABrWQBoJFKhDpwO3Ri3ibJAY3ZIs7UADpg7ItVn4I6VxQCuSU2HwXZtJoCgsFC5pbWIHYO1FA2lHS0QA)

Comment: thank you,i know what you mean.another question: when i describe the type of a varible why i can not use the type of initial capital?like String or Object? what's the difference between them?

Comment: Capitalized types of primitives, like `String`, `Object`, `Number`, etc., refer to their wrapper objects. For instance, `"hello"` is of type `string`, but `new String("hello")` is of type `String`. Other things to note are that `typeof  new String("hello")` is `'object'` and so `"hello" === new String('hello')` is `false`.

Comment: wait, why the result of  `typeof  new String("hello")` is `object`? it shouldn't be `String`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to call the `fn` function on the `b` object, but you have not defined the type of the `fn` function.

To fix this error, you can define the type of the `fn` function by specifying the parameters and return type.

For example:

```
let b: { name: string; fn: (x: number, y: number) => string }

b = {
  name: 'derek',
  fn: (x: number, y: number): string => {
    return `The result is ${x + y}`
  }
}

console.log(b.fn(1, 2))  //"The result is 3"
```